# If A^3=I, find all powers of A that are equal to the inverse of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A^3=I$, final all powers of $A$ that are equal to the inverse of $A$.

Not sure how to start the problem.

Comment: One of them is $A^2$ obviously. But there are more and it could be that $A^1$ and/or $A^0$ are also equal to the inverse of $A$ ...

Answer (score 2):

If $A\neq I$, then
$$A^n=A^{-1}\iff A^{n+1}=I\iff n+1\equiv0\pmod 3\iff n\equiv 2\pmod 3$$

If $A=I$ every power of $A$ is the inverse of $A$.

Comment: Not sure what mod is.

Comment: $n+1\equiv 0\pmod3$ means that $n+1$ is a multiple of $3$. $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$ menas that $n-2$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

At least all powers of the form $3n - 1$.

Hint for a proof:

$$A^{3n-1}A=A^{3n}=\dots?$$

Comment: @1999 No offence meant or taken, but I do not get the point. In what sense does this not qualify as an "answer"?